# kubernetes: scheduler not working sometime

Tags: kubernetes

Question:

I have one deployment app with replicas=2 and podantiaffinity configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-user
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-user
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - service-user
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 100
```

I apply it to the problem cluster, the two replicas were always be distributed to the same node by kubernetes. while it is normal when be distributed to other clusters.

It's not working when I restart service: kube-scheduler,  but when I restart service kube-apiserver, the weird operation get back to normal, Is this a kube-apiserver's bug?

Environment:

```
kubernetes: 1.21.6
kube masters: 8C16G * 3
kube nodes: 128C512G * 3
server pressure: low 
os: centos8.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t any such bug reported in kubernetes and there are many reasons for two pods getting scheduled on the same node.

Affinity and anti-affinity are useful for selecting the node and to mention whether it’s replica can be on the same node or not. However if you are planning to have them distributed equally it is suggested to use `spec.topologySpreadConstraints`, follow this [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) for more information.

Check whether all the nodes are available and there are no errors, causing the pods to not get scheduled on the remaining node. The below commands will help in basic troubleshooting while you need to browse through logs for more information

```
kubectl get nodes #command for listing all the nodes of the cluster

kubectl describe node <nodename> #command for getting full details about each node
```

Check the kube-scheduler logs and kube-apiserver logs for any error related to this abnormal distribution of the pods.

Revalidate the node labels as improper labeling might also cause issues while scheduling the pods. If you have installed any third party plugins that affect pod scheduling check whether they are configured correctly.

Kubelet is responsible for registering your node with the kube-apiserver, check whether kubelet is properly installed on all the nodes and check kubelet logs for any errors